# Writing PCM audio data to audio device from native code

Tags: android, native, pcm

Is it possible to to write PCM samples to audio device under Android directly from native code?
I've been able to reproduce PCM samples by sending data to a socket and playing with AudioTrack. Is it possible to avoid all this path to audio device by accessing directly from native code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can try to use your audio devices directly. The access works over Linux virtual device nodes placed in /dev/.

On my HTC Desire this would be

```
/dev/msm_pcm_out
```

I don't know how other devices of different vendors call this device. Its not guaranteed that this device node has the same name after reboot or OS update. So you will have a lot of nasty patching work to do once your application is shipped.

**WARNING executing the following commands will produce an infinitely white noise sound unless you kill your "cat" program or reboot your phone**

The command **(ON A ROOTED PHONE)**

```
su
```

and

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/msm_pcm_out
```

will produce white noise come out of the phone speaker.
Since cat is a C program you should be able to analyse the source code and adapt it to your program.

The catch is: your device is required to be rooted to make this happen as well as every device your application should run on.

I guess the Android way is a dirty but most portable and comfortable way to play sounds via NDK.

Comment: Don't do this - use the Android APIs.  A user should be very suspicious of any application which wants root access just to play sound.

Comment: My final words pretty much cover your conclusion. At least for people those who read them.

But thanks for clearing this up for people who don't, can't or wouldn't! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading this I ask myself why I didn't think of simply using AudioTrack from native code using JNI... That should be the best solution.